# Is there a way to generate json-schema from jsonnet?

Tags: json, configuration, jsonschema, jsonnet

[Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/) seems like a great tool for config management, and I was wondering if there's a way to generate `json-schema` using `jsonnet`?

I'm particularly interested in this because tools like [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/rjsf-team/react-jsonschema-form) and [json-editor](https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor) requires `json-schema` as input and doesn't support `jsonnet` files.

Comment: JSON Schema is also just JSON. There are many projects which use Jsonnet to make JSON Schema. Think of Jsonnet like templating for JSON.

Comment: @Relequestual can you please recommend or name a couple of projects that use Jsonnet to generate JSON Schema? I'm struggling to find any.

Comment: UK Gov content management system. Their schemas and jsonnet files are open: https://github.com/alphagov/govuk-content-schemas/blob/master/formats/answer.jsonnet for example